# Using pending signals in a process in C

Tags: c, signals

Have a process which sends a signal to another process (SIGUSR2).  This instructs the participant process that it needs to finish up the work it's doing for a previous msg
but NOT interrupt it.  The logic in the participant is when it's processing the current
msg (writing data to a port), it blocks SIGUSR2.  Then when the participant is done with
the current message, it unblocks SIGUSR2 and it checks if any SIGUSR2 signals are pending. If any are, the signal handler will fire, the code in it executes and all is good.

The problem I'm having is what if 2 or more new pending SIGUSR2 signals hit the participant
in rapid-fire succession?  The behaviour that I'm seeing is that the 1st one gets picked
up and processed but the other ones do not.  Note that SIGUSR2 is added in when the
handler function is setup so it automatically blocks the signal during processing of
received ones.

Comment: both the parent and child partipant ARE using message queues to feed them work items.  the signalling mechanism is used to perform process interruption when a high priority message arrives that needs to break a message being sent, process the new incoming one and then re-do the one that got interrupted.  The use case I'm testing here though is a pending signal that needs to be accounted for so when the participant finishes work on the 1st one, it does AND THEN receives the signal indicating that there is another pending high priority message to process.

Comment: Please edit your comment into your question.  How can we note that SIGUSR2 is added at any time when you show no code whatsoever?

Comment: You should read the POSIX [Signal Concepts](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) section. You may also need to read the analogous material from your operating system's manual.  The POSIX section says _"If a subsequent occurrence of a pending signal is generated, it is implementation-defined as to whether the signal is delivered or accepted more than once in circumstances other than those in which queuing is required."_  It isn't clear when signals must be queued, but if a signal is pending, further occurrences of the same signal may be discarded.

Comment: What you doubt that the client process is sending the signal to the participant??  The bit about further occurrences being discarded is what I'm experiencing.  great...

Comment: No.  What I'm not sure about is if three occurrences of the same signal are sent while delivery is suspended, it is possible that two of the occurrences are effectively lost — only one of the signals is sent once delivery is enabled again.  I think the specification says "implementation-defined" for that, so you need to find your implementation's definition of what happens.

Comment: Linux, for one, will not queue multiples of normal signals, but will real-time ones.

Comment: so by bumping the sending process to be a real time priority scheduled proc, it will send these in a queue?

Comment: Maybe — you'll have to read the manual for your system carefully.

Comment: this use case is one of those rarely if ever used in the system...trying to capture all the scenarios that will/might play out.  thx for your help guys.

Comment: http://davmac.org/davpage/linux/rtsignals.html

Comment: I can confirm using sigqueue to send the real time signals to the participant process, it now receives all pending signals properly as expected.

Comment: first time I ever used real time signals....and that's 35 years in on linux/unix.  learn something new every day...